# Проблема с парсингом сайта www.365-858.com

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

Хочу спарсить страничку https://www.365-858.com/#/IP/B18. Но, на выходе в html передаётся информация не то что ожидал увидеть. Хочу информацию со странички структурировать в таблицы. Вот, то что есть:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "eager"  #  interactive
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps,

                          executable_path=r'C:\Users\chromedriver.exe'
                          )
driver.get("https://www.365-858.com/")

#driver.close()
```

Comment: Страницу прогружает java.Загружайте страницу чем нибудь типа selenium и птом уже парсите ее

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: @Namerek какая java там подгружает? Не ведите автора в заблуждение.

Comment: @ВадимАлександру, удачи в парсинге этой страницы через requests + bs4

Comment: Данные на странице подгружается через js, а не java

Comment: Товарищи с selenium не погружает страницу.